# Correct status code to return when API calls a 3rd party API and that call fails

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-codes

I am developing a Web API which, as one of its functions, sends out SMSes. So when the consuming front-end requests the API to send out an SMS, the API in turn calls another API (from a 3rd party SMS service provider) and sends the SMS.

If the SMS fails to send for whatever reason (i.e. the SMS service provider tells my API that the SMS couldn't go through), what status code should my API return?

**EDIT:**

500 Internal Server Error doesn't seem right as there is no issue on the server. The SMS service provider simply couldnt send out the SMS (perhaps because the client has run out of credits, or the cellphone number is wrong
)

Comment: `ServiceUnavailable` maybe? But you should have different responses and status codes for different scenarios. If it is wrong number for example, then `BadRequest` should be sent... Maybe you can also look at the responses you get from that service and just wrap them in a cleaner response that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Harun. Great idea. I see that, for example, if the SMS Service Provider successfully sends out the SMS, it returns a 202 Accepted. My API could then return that back to its consuming client.

Comment: And whatever the SMS Service Provider returns when there is a failure, my API will simply return that to the consuming client too.

Comment: I agree with @HarunCerim. 503 Service Unavailable seems like your best bet: "The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some delay." Basically tells the client that they can't do anything right now, but the endpoint is still good and it might work again later.

Comment: Thanks Chris!!!